# No spell checker is showing (English)

Tags: android-10, gboard, spell-check

I'm using this phone: https://www.infinixmobility.com/smartphone/smart-5/specs

But I don't see any spell checker in it.

In **Settings > System > Languages & input > Spell checker**,
It should show **Google Spell Checker** here I guess.

[image]

[image]

That's why, it's not showing **red underline** with the misspelled word.

[image]

The **blue underline** is from **Gboard** I think. But why there is no spell checker?

Is it a bug? Looking for help. Thanks in advance.